# how to create a loading page after a button event in wp8 xaml C#

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, windows-phone-8

hi i need to how can i make a overlay like page in xaml for windows phone ? Like, if i tap a button it will show a overlay like message loading... and then actually start to work. All i have been able to create a popup in xaml.

```
<Popup x:Name="myPopup" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" >
    <Grid >
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBlock FontSize="25" Grid.Column="1" Margin="20" Text="loading"/>
    </Grid>
</Popup>
```

Can you plz tell me how can make overlay like message ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need and overlay there it is.
First you need an usercontrol.

```
<UserControl x:Class="ABC.Test.OverLay"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
d:DesignHeight="800" d:DesignWidth="480">

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="400"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="400"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="1">
        <ProgressBar IsIndeterminate="True" Foreground="Red" Height="80" Width="480" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
        <TextBlock Text="loading" Foreground="Red" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontSize="20"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

In Codebehind :

```
public OverLay()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.LayoutRoot.Height = Application.Current.Host.Content.ActualHeight;
        this.LayoutRoot.Width = Application.Current.Host.Content.ActualWidth;
        SystemTray.IsVisible = false;
    }
```

In the page where you would show the overlay, create an instance of popup just like this:

```
private Popup popup;
```

Initialize it after **InitializeComponent()**,like this :

```
this.popup = new Popup();
```

on the event where you need the overlay to show up, try like this :

```
        this.LayoutRoot.Opacity = 0.2;
        OverLay _ovr = new OverLay();            
        this.popup.Child = _ovr;
        this.popup.IsOpen = true;
        BackgroundWorker _worker = new BackgroundWorker();
        _worker.DoWork += (s, a) =>
        {
            //you can do your work here.
            Thread.Sleep(3000);
        };
        _worker.RunWorkerCompleted += (s, a) =>
        {
            popup.IsOpen = false;
            this.LayoutRoot.Opacity = 1.0;
        };

        _worker.RunWorkerAsync();
```

Find the working [Here on Nokia Developers community](http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/Create_simple_overlay_with_UserControl_in_Windows_Phone)